# Escaping double quotes and the Web

Tags: c++, c, web-services

I am trying to get the following sent in an xml.

```
<Request xmlns="http://abc.org/1.1/Listener.wsdl">&lt;serverstatusinquiry xmlns="http://abc.org/messages"/&gt;</Request>
```

The problem I am facing is the text part of the Request node. I am printing the text as follows.

```
"<serverstatusinquiry xmlns=\"http://abc.org/messages\"/>"
```

But I end up with:

```
&lt;serverstatusinquiry xmlns=&quot;http://abc.org/messages&quot;/&gt;
```

I understand `&quot;` stands for double quotes, is there a way I can force it to actually output `"` instead of `&quot;`? Is there anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: What library/... are you using for this?

Comment: Also, is it actually a problem that you get `&quot;` there? Any program processing the generated XML should handle it correctly.

Comment: The library is Axis2C which internally uses Guththila. I am trying to bring it in as much synch as possible since we are facing some issues in parsing.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `&#60;` for *<* (Less than), > `&#62;` for *>* (Greater than), and `&#34;` for *"*

```
<Request xmlns="http://abc.org/1.1/Listener.wsdl">&#60;serverstatusinquiry xmlns=&#34http://abc.org/messages&#34/&#62;</Request>Quotation).
```